# Toggle between 2 classes Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a button I want to toggle between theses classes.

I want to run `full-page-wrapper` first and then toggle again `content-wrapper` and keep like this.

This toggles once and doesn't work after.

```
 $('#sidebar-btn').click(function () {
   $('.content-wrapper').toggleClass('content-wrapper full-page-wrapper');
});
```

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle to highlight the issue.

Comment: `$('.content-wrapper, .full-page-wrapper').toggleClass(...`

Answer (score 1):

When you toggle the first time you are removing your content-wrapper class making it impossible for your selector to find element with a content-wrapper class. try giving it an id and toggle on the element id.

```
$('#classToRemove').toggleClass('content-wrapper full-page-wrapper');
```

Comment: Nice catch! Good job